# I forgot my password (Ubuntu 16.04) & can't open GRUB now

Tags: 16.04, grub2, password

I am trying to access the GRUB menu by pressing shift, esc, space, etc, but I just can't get into it. I can't change the `/etc/default/grub` file unless I login. But I lost my password, so I can't do that!

Comment: use Oli's answer (`chroot` with live media). If you can't `chroot`, use the live media to boot, mount the root partition and edit `/etc/default/grub` (comment out the `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT...` line) then reboot to recovery and follow the standard procedure

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LiveCD Rescatux to recover your system:
[Rescatux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/)

Rescatux is a GNU/Linux rescue cd (and eventually also Windows) but it is not like other rescue disks. Rescatux comes with Rescapp. Rescapp is a nice wizard that will guide you through your rescue tasks.

[How to use rescatux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGA8e_A2PeA)

Might it helps.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers").